# Creating an implied floor with light

Tags: adobe-photoshop, lighting-effects

The title isn't the best way to describe what I want to do, probably.  I'll try to explain better here.  The relevant selection is below.  You can see that inside the door is a bright white space, but it ends sharply below.  I want to project a gradient light out below the door to hide that sharp edge and create a sort of implied floor, as if the light is shining onto the floor.  [This ad](http://files1.coloribus.com/files/adsarchive/part_1047/10472155/file/mini-car-mini-service-tailor-small-36398.jpg) has what I'm talking about.

I've tried using the different light features on photoshop with little luck.  If my difficulty getting across what I mean didn't tip you off, I don't have a whole lot of experience in photoshop.  Is there a good way to pull this off and make it look natural?

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Ok I am up to the challenge...

First we need to re-frame the image.

Now, What kind of floor do you need?

[image]

1. For an Ultra Glossy Floor, just copy your door, Skew it, mask it and add a gradient opacity.
   The same for the frame of the door.
2. For a Satin floor, apply a gaussian blur to this same object and use some mesh fill to add the spilled light. Play with transparencies again. (There is a little gap between the rooms becouse of the gaussian blur)
3. For a Matt floor use a mesh fill. I actually did this with vectors but the process is the same.

You could add a texture, just adjust the perspective acordingly.

Comment: Same door! :) http://i.crackedcdn.com/phpimages/photoshop/7/4/2/484742_v1.jpg

Answer (score 4):

First pick a spot for your light source and rough idea of where that would cause the light to be. I'm going to stick it over here:

[image]

Then use the Pen Tool to create the area the light will be visible:

[image]

Create a new layer and make your path in a vector mask:

[image]

I used a White to Transparent gradient and started from about where my lightsource is in the direction I sketched:

[image]

Adjust the Feathering on the Vector Mask:

[image]

Now the benefit of using a Vector Mask is we can refine it:

[image]

And that would do it:

[image]

For the picture you posted its almost like there's a second light source which are the brighter spots. Could just use the same process again deciding where and how you want those to be. If the door is staying white like this then I'd probably add a much stronger gradient by the "edge" since this looks weak compared to how bright the inside is, but I'll leave the fine tuning to you.

Comment: I think one of the problems with this image, however, is that the lightsource seems to be all encompassing, unifrom, if you will.  To that end, I would say that slanting the pale light that you have there may not do it justice. Also, the fall-off between your dark floor and the light floor on the outside of the door is too contrasting. It could, of course, be a step down, but I'd still expect to see some kind of feature between the door and the outside (like a step or something).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways you can do this, and it really depends on the overall look you are personally going for. The ad you referenced is a bit different as it doesn't have a sharp light source as the image you are working with. Here is a quick workup of possibly the simplest way to do this:

[image]

Using a mask to create the overall boundaries of the light spilling in through the doorway, I used a solid white layer and then a black-to-transparent layer. Using the separate layers makes it easy to adjust the depth and location of the gradient part.

[image]

If you want to add a texture to the floor, create or download a pattern and use a Layer Blending Mode to adjust to your liking.

[image]

Hope this helps!